# Why does IPython display `super` objects differently from the regular Python interactive interpreter?

Tags: ipython

When I create an unbound `super` object, `IPython` displays it as `<super: None, None>`.  Yet both `str(...)` and `repr(...)`, as well as the interactive ordinary Python interpreter, display it as `<super: <class 'object'>, NULL>`, which is more informative.  I know that [IPythons displayhook](http://ipython.org/ipython-doc/stable/api/generated/IPython.core.displayhook.html) is different from the [default Python displayhook](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/sys.html#sys.displayhook), but does this difference explain the different representations?  Where does `IPython` get its display for builtin objects from?

In `ipython3`:

```
In [1]: super(object)
Out[1]: <super: None, None>

In [2]: str(_1), repr(_1)
Out[2]: ("<super: <class 'object'>, NULL>", "<super: <class 'object'>, NULL>")
```

In `python3.3`:

```
>>> super(object)
<super: <class 'object'>, NULL>
>>> from IPython.core import displayhook, interactiveshell
>>> print(displayhook.DisplayHook(interactiveshell.InteractiveShell()).compute_format_data(super(object)))
WARNING: IPython History requires SQLite, your history will not be saved
({'text/plain': '<super: None, None>'}, {})
```

What's going on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well spotted, thanks. This was a bug in IPython, and I've just made [this pull request](https://github.com/ipython/ipython/pull/5003) to fix it.

IPython calculates representations of a number of builtin types in `IPython.lib.pretty`. This is useful for things like compiled regex patterns, where the default repr is just `<_sre.SRE_Pattern object at 0x7f...`.